# SyntaxError: missing : after property id (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Really not sure what is wrong, and can't seem to find a solution from other related error posts.
So here

```
function doit(){
var handler = action.setup({
$.get('https://example.com/number.txt', function(data) {ref = parseInt(data) + 1;}),
number: ref,
});
}
```

All i want to do is get the number from https://example.com/number.txt and use it's result.

No matter what i do, it kept saying `SyntaxError: missing : after property id`

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? How did this code some to be? A get request inside of an object with no id looks out of place

Comment: `{function()}` certainly is invalid. What does `action.setup()` expect as argument?

Comment: I have updated the code. It's only a part of a full code, and i don't think i should post every part to prove a point. Don't seem to know why it's been down voted though.

Comment: In the full code, do you really call `$.get()` inside of an object? I think that's the problem; especially since you have no value for it. Also, you might have trouble use the result of `$.get` as key in an object.

Comment: I called $.get() because i need to use it's ouput as you can see `number: ref`. I believe people should have came up with a solution other than just down voting.

Comment: Well you should be explaining what you expect this to do. It simply can't work as you have it now. `$.get()` returns a promise which is not a valid object property and even if it was there is no value for that property. You are trying to construct an invalid object and we don't know what it is you expect from this

Comment: All i want to do is get the number from `https://example.com/number.txt` and use it's result.

Comment: OK...next issue is  `$.get()` is asynchronous so you can't synchronously do what you are trying to do either. Needs to be done after `$.get()` resolves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.get()` is asynchronous so you need to do something like:

```
function doit() {
  $.get('https://example.com/number.txt', function(data) {    
    var ref = parseInt(data) + 1;    
    var handler = action.setup({number: ref});
    // work with handler here after request has completed
  });
}
```

If you had planned on returning `handler` from `doIt()` you need to return the `$.get()` promise instead or use `async/await`

Comment: for future reference a simple one or two sentence explanation of expectations would have resolved a lot of confusion..."here's what I am trying to do...here's the code that breaks trying it"

Comment: I have edited the post to indicate expectation. Thanks once again. Appreciated.